# rpivotTable not fitting in my Shiny Dashboard page

Tags: r, shiny, rpivottable

I am using rpivoTable package in my shiny dashboard. 
The problem is that my tables has close to 25 variables (columns) whereas I am only able to view 10 columns. Rest are out of view and there's no slider also to view them.

Best,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I find one way -- add css to that pivot

```
tags$head(tags$style( type = 'text/css',  '#pivot{ overflow-x: scroll; }')),
          rpivotTableOutput('pivot', width = "100%", height = "500px")
```

for example

UI

```
library(shiny)
library(rpivotTable)
library(shinydashboard)
shinyUI(dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "example"),
  dashboardSidebar(disable = T),
  dashboardBody(

      tags$head(tags$style( type = 'text/css',  '#pivot{ overflow-x: scroll; }')),
      rpivotTableOutput('pivot', width = "100%", height = "500px")
  )

))
```

server

```
df=data.frame(lapply(1:25,function(i)i=rnorm(20)))
colnames(df)=as.character(letters[1:25])

shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {

  output$pivot <- renderRpivotTable({
    rpivotTable(data = df)
  })


})
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. But my output is not just a table its complete pivot structure. This is my output ....  output$pivot <- renderRpivotTable({
    rpivotTable(mydata)
  })

Comment: how you use it in ui ( or server part of UI)? add css where you code how to show your `output$pivot`

Comment: Add example to my answer

Comment: I am adding this pivot in a dashboard tab..     
tabItem(tabName = "trains",
              fluidRow(br(),rpivotTable::rpivotTableOutput('pivot'))       
      )

Comment: try `tabItem(tabName = "trains", fluidRow(br() ,
                                     tags$head(tags$style( type = 'text/css',  '#pivot{ overflow-x: scroll; }'))
                                     ,rpivotTable::rpivotTableOutput('pivot')) )`  or see my edit

Comment: @Batanichek Would it be possible to do the same without using `shiny` ? (how to pass custom `css` directly to a chunk in `flexdashboard`)

Comment: @StevenBeaupré If i understand right you need somethink like `---
title: "Test"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    css: styles.css
---

```{r}
library(rpivotTable)
rpivotTable(iris)
``` ` in markdown  and `.rpivotTable{ overflow-x: scroll; }` in styles.css